# MySQL efficient table duplication

Tags: mysql

I have a relatively expensive process that requires a 'self join' that is clogging my computation time. Consider the following script:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdb.table1
SELECT * FROM db.sometable WHERE {condition};
ALTER TABLE tempdb.table1 ADD INDEX idx_t({columns for join});

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdb.table2
SELECT * FROM tempdb.table1;
ALTER TABLE tempdb.table2 ADD INDEX idx_t({columns for join});
```

In this case I'm required to compute the Index twice before I can attempt the join. If I create the second table with the 'LIKE' operator, the new table will be created with the index structure but it will still need to process while the table is being populated.

Is there someway to completely duplicate the table, indexes and all in one step? It would narrow the computation time considerably as it would just need to find memory for this new table as opposed to reperforming a lot of computation. As mentioned in the comments, this is a problem I bump into regularly for various applications. My goal with this question is not to optimize a particular application but want information on this issue in general.

Comment: It is possible that you can optimize the original query without creating temporary tables.  You should ask another question and include the query you want to optimize.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is a problem I bump into often regardless of the exact context. So I'm more interested in this question than some general optimization approaches.

Comment: @jamesselmore . . . Interesting.  I almost never have to create temporary tables to optimize queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, another concern holding me back from posting a full script is that the application / logic is not mine to share as it's work for my employer. I would be very surprised if you could perform the necessary task without temp tables and you have certainly perked my interest. I'll see if there is a way to re-contextualize the script in such a way that I don't have any reservations sharing

Answer (score 0):

Create the table using the 'LIKE' operator as you have mentioned.
Then, disable the indexes before you copy the data from the source table.
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE destdb.table1 LIKE srcdb.table1;
ALTER TABLE destdb.table1 DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO destdb.table1 SELECT * FROM srcdb.table1;
ALTER TABLE destdb.table1 ENABLE KEYS;
```

Comment: When I reenable the keys, will it not need to reprocess everything still? Not clear that this solves the problem as much as breaks it into two different steps

Comment: Re-enabling the index will create the index data. You can't avoid that but by disabling the index before insert, you get better performance. Insert will be faster because it does not need to update the index for every insert.
If your table have foreign keys, you can also disable foreign keys and gain better performance.

Comment: Ok, but how is that different from what I've written above? Where I write into a second table and then apply the indexes

Comment: This script will work in any case. I don't need to know what indexes are in the source table.

Comment: That's not my point / concern. My point is that I offered a solution where I duplicate the table without any keys or indexes and then create them with an alter statement. You offered that I create a duplicate table with the keys disabled insert the data then reactivate the keys. It sounds like there is no computational difference. Is this correct?

Comment: I see. Performance-wise, this should be the same as your sample script.